# Why 'text-overflow' doesn't work when children elements has 'float'?

Tags: css-float, css

I have a piece of HTML codes as follows:

```
<div style="width:100px;border: 1px solid red;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap;margin:0 auto">
    <span style="float: left">LeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeft</span>
</div>
```

But `ellipsis` seems doesn't work. If I remove the `float` attribute of `span`, it can display in a normal way with 'LeftLeft...'. Does `text-overflow` and `float` conflict with each other ?

Comment: "Does 'text-overflow' and 'float' conflict with each other ?" Yes, in a way...

Comment: why do you want it to float left? doesnt it do that automaticly

Answer (score 5):

[The spec for `text-overflow` property](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-ui/#text-overflow) says that

> This property specifies rendering when **inline content** overflows
>   its block container element ("the block") in its inline progression
>   direction that has ‘overflow’ other than ‘visible’.

Floating children are not *inline content*, they are considered as special kind of block content (their computed value of `display` is `block`). That's why they need to have their own `text-overflow` (because this property is not inherited) along with width limitation. e.g.

```
<div style="width:100px;border: 1px solid red;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap;margin:0 auto">
    <span style="float: left; max-width: 100%; overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;">LeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeft</span>
</div>
```

([see JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RyyMs/))

Comment: Just an add: also `display: inline-block` is not considered as inline content.

Answer (score 0):

Attempt to use this style on the span element:

```
<span style="float:left; overflow:hidden"><!--Content--></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yea considering overflow CSS property on a parent element and property is set to auto or hidden then the parent will expand to contain the floats, effectively clearing it for succeeding elements.

So float property wont work at all.

Not sure if someone have any hack around it.

Check the doc, http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#float
Its for CSS3 but applies to CSS2 also.